# plotting 2D slice of arbitrary orientation through 3D data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I have a 3D regular grid of data.  I would like to write a routine allowing the user to specify a plane slicing through the data with arbitrary orientation and returning a contour plot of the data in the plane.  Is there a ready-made way in matplotlib to do this?  Could find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `roll` function of numpy to rotate your plane and make it parallel with a base plane. now you can choose your plane and plot. Only problem is that at close to edges the value from one side will be added to opposite side.

Comment: Thanks, but are you sure it's `roll`?  I thought roll just shifted elements around.  Here's the doc I'm thinking of: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html

Comment: following is a small code i have made to roll a 3d matrix 
`a=np.asarray(range(0,9**3))`
`b=np.reshape(a,(9,9,9))`
`for i in range (0,9):`
    `c=np.roll(b,i,2)`